# button awkwardly positioned when i use custom select box

Tags: jquery, css

I just came across this plugin online called , fancySelect and decided to use it ,

basically i need my custom select box and the button to be horizontally side-by-side and vertically centered to each other. My HTML looks like below:

```
<section class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <form class="select-branch" action="" method="POST">

                            <label for="branch-select">Hospital</label>

                            <select class="" id="branch-select" name="hospital" type="text">

                                <option value="Manipal Hospital Bangalore">Hosmat Hospital Bangalore</option>

                                <option value="Manipal Northside Hospital">test Hosmat Northside Hospital</option>

                            </select>

                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">contact this location</button>

                        </form>

                </div>

            </div>    

    </section>
```

Here is what i tried , **[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lopa23bs/1/)** , now see how the button comes so down , almost like i positioned it and than gave it a negative offset from the top , i have't done anything of that sort , so well why is this happening ? and how to i vertically center both to each other ?

I am really interested in why this is happening , can anybody answer the **WHY** question here.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: setting vertical-align: 'middle' on fancy-select div seems to work.  Not sure whats going on with the plug-in so don't have your WHY answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this weird positioning due to the fact you're injecting HTML around the `select`.

Put `vertical-align: bottom` in CSS on `.fancy-select`.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lopa23bs/2/).

Answer (score 1):

add `vertical-align: middle;` to `div.fancy-select`.

Why? because you need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to each element you want to vertically align.

ie, if you also want the label aligned, then add `vertical-align: middle;`.

Answer (score 1):

put  following for your div fancy-select ,fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/Lopa23bs/4/)

```
display :inline-flex
```